# laravel many to many with chaining where clause

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

I have a given table :

```
tools     toolparts      parts     part_details
-----     ---------      -----     ------------
id*       id*            id*       id*
name      tool_id        name      part_id
          part_id                  total (int) 
-----     ---------      -----     ------------
```

the relation between Tools and Parts is ManyToMany. and the relation between parts and part_details is one to many.

with Laravel model, how can I get tool with part that has the biggest part_details.total ??

```
//tool model
public function parts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Part', 'tool_part');
}

//part model
public function tools()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tool', 'tool_part')
}

public function details(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Part_detail');
}

//partDetail model
public function part(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Part');
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
  $tools = Tool::with('parts', 'parts.details')->has('parts')->get();
  return $tools;
}
```

what I expected is something like :

Controller

```
public function index()
{
  $tool = Tool::with('SinglePartThatHasHigestTotalInPartDetail');

}
```

Any Idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Manage my problem with "hacky" ways. if someone have a better and more elegant solution, please tell me.

//tool model

```
public function partWithHighestTotalDelivery($trans_date = null){
    if (is_null($trans_date)) {
        $trans_date = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    $parts = $this->parts;

    $highest_total_delivery = 0;

    foreach ($parts as $key => $part) {
        $part->detail;

        $total_delivery = $part->first_value;

        if (isset( $part->detail->total_delivery )) {
            $total_delivery += $part->detail->total_delivery;     
        }

        if ($highest_total_delivery < $total_delivery ) {
           $highest_total_delivery = $total_delivery;

           $part->total_delivery = $highest_total_delivery;

           $result = $part;
        }   

    }

    if (!isset($result)) {
        $result = null;
    }

    $this->part = $result;
}
```

In controller i have :

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $tools = Tool::has('parts')
    ->get();

    $tools->each(function($tool){
      $tool->partWithHighestTotalDelivery();
    });

    return $tools;
}
```

with this, I need to run `tool->partWithHighestTotalDelivery()` tools.count times. which is take noticeable process if the tools is many.

and also, the code I post and the question I ask has a slightly difference.that's for a simplicity sake's

Answer (score 0):

Use the the **hasManyThrough** Relationship to get the all part details related to tool and then you can check the one by one record and get the highest total of the tool part.

**// Tool Model**

```
public function partsdetails()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\PartDetail', 'App\Part','tool_id','part_id');
}
```

**In Your controller**

```
$data = Tool::all(); 
        $array = [];
        if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
               $array[$value->id] = Tool::find($value->id)->partsdetails()->max('total');
            }
        }

        if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)) {
            $maxs = array_keys($array, max($array));
            print_r($maxs);// This array return the max total of the tool related parts
        } 
        else{
         echo "No Data Available";
        }
```

Comment: With this approach I need to run Tool::find($value->id)->partsdetails()->sum('total') so many times. and sum() is not something that I need here.

Comment: @punk73 You need the tool id which part_details total is highest. Then my answer is correct.Because $maxs return the tool Id which is the highest total of the part_details.

Comment: I need one tool to contain one part that has highest part_details.total;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates) for querying to get the desired result,

In your code use `max()` function,

```
public function index()
{
  $tool = Tool::with(['parts.part_details' => function ($query) {
      $max = $query->max('total');
      $query->where('total',$max);
  })->first();

}
```

I haven't tested this but you can do like this.

Comment if you will get any errors.

Comment: let me explain my problem more. with the details I mentioned in the question, what I tried to achieve is : 1 tool has 1 part that has a biggest total amongs other. ( please note that 1 tool has more than 1 parts since it is many to many )

Comment: Yeah. Your question and answer seem different. But it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the part detail and get the tool(s) from there:

```php
$maxPartDetail = Part_detail::orderByDesc('total')->first();
$tools = $maxPartDetail->part->tools;
```